# bode plot of LM3481 as boost converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, simulation, boost, texas-instruments, buck-boost

I have simulated an open loop boost converter using LM3481 average model, given by texas instruments and I got a very strange bode plot (More precisely, strage phase response), please can you tell me why I did not get the general forme response?

Here is the circuit simulated in TINA TI simulator:
[image]

Expected forme of the phase response
[image]

Comment: `please can anyone knows what I have missed ?` You haven't told us what you're expecting to see :)

Comment: I have added what I'm expecting from my simulation, If you notice, as the frequency increases, the phase decreases. In my simulation as the frequency increases, the, the phase tends to 0°.

Comment: That's helpful, thank you. Have you figured out the appropriate transfer function for this circuit? I think that could help you see how to plot the bode plot correctly.

Comment: I did not find it in the datasheet, but it says that it is a current mode boost converter controller, so I'm expecting the device to behave like a standard current mode controller, this is why i give you the standard response of current mode controller. The link bellow helps you understand the transfer function of this kinf of controllers: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva452/slva452.pdf

Comment: If you are operating that converter in continuous conduction mode (CCM), then you should see a the effect of the right-half-plane zero bringing the phase further down. Unless it is located at high frequency and the converter is in light CCM? Also, unless heavy internal compensation, sub-harmonic poles effects should show up at \$F_{sw}/2\$ as the second plot shows, stressing phase lag at this point.